# Hide fancybox 5 window from iframe

Tags: fancybox

How can I close fancybox iframe window in version 5? (without any click)
I need it after form submit, when task is finished.

---

```
Fancybox.bind("[data-fancybox='iframe1']", {
    defaultType:"iframe",
    preload:false,
    },
});
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close Fancybox anywhere from the code using `close` static method:

```js
Fancybox.close();
```

But, if you want to close Fancybox from within the iframe page, you simply have to access Fancybox from the parent page:

```js
window.parent.Fancybox.close();
```

Demo - https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/fancybox-iframe-qr4mx8